# Cannot run index.js in nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express

First i am create

1. Code folder in c: drive
2. Then navigate Code in cmd
3. Create package.json file with following code

   ```
   var express = require('express')
     , app = express.createServer();

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.send('hello world');
   });
   ```

   `app.listen(3000)`
4. Then install npm using npm install in code folder.
5. Then code have new folder node_modules and package.json file. Inside node_modules folder express folder is available inside 2 folder is available lib and node_modules and many more files is there. Now i am confused to run my first project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "Hello World" example, extracted from the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), suggested above:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // here I use the express() method, instead of the createServer()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put the code inside a file called `app.js` instead of `package.json`. Then you should be able to just run the app using `node app.js`. The `package.json` can be created with `npm init` and `npm --save express`.

Or you can use the `express-generator` tool as described in the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html).

Comment: in package.json file i am not put code. index.js file have code

Comment: @jcragun It's worth mentioning that `express.createServer()` is deprecated, `var app = express()` should be used instead.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros Okey but in which folder i have to put index.js?

Comment: @PareshGami Usually, the `index.js` file is placed in the app root directory - in your case, is `c:\code`. Then you just run `node index.js` and it should run, since you already installed the `express` module. Just keep in mind that `express.createServer()` is deprecated. If you have any doubts, just read the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) that @jcragun suggested.

Comment: Can you give hello world sample code.? and i like to ask about how it is deprecated. I am downloading 4.8.3 version of express

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros good call out on the deprecation. I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('Hello World');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```